# Retrieve data from sqlserver in vb.net using entity framework and native sql

Tags: vb.net, winforms, entity-framework-4, native-sql

I want to retrieve data in Winforms using vb.net, entity framework and native sql. I have used the code below which allows me to add data to the sql:

```
Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim db As New SampleDBEntities
    Dim bs As New BindingSource
    bs.DataSource = db.Cars.Local
    DataGridView1.DataSource = bs
End Sub
```

But I don't know how to fire a query to retrieve data from database. Suppose I want to get all the records from Cars table in my Database named SampleDB.
So I need `"SELECT * FROM Cars"`,
but how to use this query?

Comment: Either you work with SQL directly (through SQL or stored procedures) and communicate with the server using SqlConnection, SqlCommand and perhaps DataReader or DataAdapter or you correctly use the Entity Framework that you have configured and talk to that. Have you set up EF in your project already?

Comment: yes I have already set up EF in my project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either you work with SQL directly (through SQL or stored procedures) and communicate with the server using SqlConnection, SqlCommand and perhaps DataReader or DataAdapter or you correctly use the Entity Framework that you have configured.

I'm not really into VB.Net, so it'll be pseudocode, but you need to be addressing your EF context.

Something like

```
using (myEntityModel context = new myEntityModel()) 
{
    MyResult = context.Cars.where(c => c.model == "myModel").ToList();
}
```

Comment: I got a solution `context.Cars.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Cars").ToList()`. Thanks anyways for trying to answer my question.

Comment: @user2524507 By entering an SqlQuery into EF, you're completely missing the point of the EF itself. It was designed to be a bridge between your dotNet code and a SQLServer (or the likes). If you want to access SQL directly by injecting SQL statements, you should look at the SqlClient assembly in System.Data and work with classes such as SqlConnection and SqlCommand.

Answer (score 4):

To get all the cars it would be:

```
Using db As New SampleDBEntities
  Dim cars = db.Cars.ToList
End Using
```

To get all cars by type, if you have a 'type' field in that entity.

```
Using db As New SampleDBEntities
  Dim mazdaCars = db.Cars.Where(Function(c) c.Type = "Mazda").ToList
End Using
```

ENtity Framework was built for LINQ and Lambda. Be sure to close/dispose your entity container object.

Comment: I got a solution `context.Cars.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Cars").ToList()`. Thanks anyways for trying to answer my question.

Comment: Hey @OneFineDay, I am starting a Windows forms project using EF and VB.NET, I don't know how to access the data from my vb file. Do you have any idea or tutorial to give me please ?